# How to get the "list of active timers" of a WindowTimer implemented object

Tags: javascript, timer, javascript-objects, object-property

The W3C specification states "Each object that implements the WindowTimers interface has a list of active timers." But I have never seen anywhere how to get to that list and inspect it Does that imply that it's implementation specific and not meant to be accessible?

Or can you get to the list of active timers, inspect it to get the highest Id (as this is what I have seen implemented) or even tell how many of each Timeouts or Intervals are set at a given time?

I have read several threads on a way to kill all Intervals (and/or Timeouts) and with answers about creating a blank new one and then removing up to that newly created timer. That is why I started researching: to remove any timer, but that assumes that timers are created incrementally. I was wondering: some specifications (for example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) mentions creating intervalIDs but never specify in what way, and W3C speaks of handles rather than integer Ids. Also I understand that the list (for each object) is unique, so the timers (intervals and timeouts) must be aware of what they actually are.